# How can I shuffle an array?

Tags: javascript

I want to shuffle an array of elements in JavaScript like these:

```
[0, 3, 3] -> [3, 0, 3]
[9, 3, 6, 0, 6] -> [0, 3, 6, 9, 6]
[3, 3, 6, 0, 6] -> [0, 3, 6, 3, 6]
```

Comment: This has been answered a number of times on stackoverflow. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-a-javascript-array here's another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086262/javascript-array-shuffle-with-padding

Comment: A good resource for [JavaScript Shuffle, Deal, Draw](http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/js-shufl.htm#FnB) and other date and mathematic stuff.

Comment: What about a one-liner? The returned array is shuffled.
arr1.reduce((a,v)=>a.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length), 0, v) && a, [])

Comment: you can use sort() with pseudo random function, while if you have non numeric members, you can simply add numeric field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25984542/1238884

Comment: @VitaliPom Don't use sort() with random().  Sort does not expect random result and the result may not be uniform.  Microsoft's browser ballot was [bugged](https://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html) because of this.

Comment: @brunettdan I wrote this one liner which does not use splice and is much faster: `arr1.reduceRight((p,v,i,a)=>(v=i?~~(Math.random()*(i+1)):i, v-i?[a[v],a[i]]=[a[i],a[v]]:0, a),a)`; Also check out [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25984542/893578).

Comment: @Sheepy thanks! Didn't know that. Took me a while to understand what I wrote what I answered on that :) Thanks for clarifying your answer.

Answer (score 1100, accepted):

Use [the modern version of the Fisher–Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm):

```
/**
 * Shuffles array in place.
 * @param {Array} a items An array containing the items.
 */
function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}
```

### ES2015 (ES6) version

```
/**
 * Shuffles array in place. ES6 version
 * @param {Array} a items An array containing the items.
 */
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}
```

Note however, that swapping variables with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Swapping_variables) causes significant performance loss, as of October 2017.

### Use

```
var myArray = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
shuffle(myArray);
```

### Implementing prototype

Using `Object.defineProperty` ([method taken from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30391923/1256925)) we can also implement this function as a prototype method for arrays, without having it show up in loops such as `for (i in arr)`. The following will allow you to call `arr.shuffle()` to shuffle the array `arr`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'shuffle', {
    value: function() {
        for (let i = this.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            [this[i], this[j]] = [this[j], this[i]];
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: This method (as well as the one below) both modify the original array. That's no big deal, but the example of how to call it is a bit weird.

Comment: @Michael +1 for pointing out that reassignment is unnecessary. In fact it's misleading, and probably should have been the FIRST thing pointed out in this comment thread.

Comment: I find the ES6 swap to be slower (once I got it to work. You have to have a semicolon before a [--all the more reason to just always use them.).

Comment: @trlkly: ES2015 variant will be slower due to the use of destructuring assignment. Hopefully engines will optimize it soon.

Comment: Why isn't there a test of `i !== j`? That should save a bit of time

Comment: Should iterate over the array from 0 to length-1, otherwise plenty of cache-misses!

Comment: Why `return a;`? Is it simply to allow for things like `shuffle(a).slice(...)`?

Comment: What is the purpose of `(i + 1)` in `const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));`? Wouldn't `Math.floor(Math.random() * i));` be better?

Comment: Is it still true that the destructuring assignment incurs significant performance loss?

Comment: In Node (11), this doesn't seem to be the case. In browsers, it's only marginally different, see https://jsperf.com/shuffle-using-destructuring-assignment

Comment: @Regnoult `j` is random, so no, you can't do that. However the loop could start at `i = a.length / 2 + 1`. You don't have to shuffle the same items twice, indeed.

Comment: @aioobe yes for that purpose.
@AlexisWilke if `i === j`, example `i=j=2` then the code does `[a[2], a[2]] = [a[2], a[2]]`. No point. And no, you need to iterate on all elements. Think about the case random returns always `1`. Your change wouldn't shuffle half of the array.

Comment: Sort 1, 10, 100 ? Why is this accepted ?

Comment: It doesn't seem semantically correct to use *const* for a variable that changes its value on every iteration of the loop. It's also more to type than *let* or *var*. ;-)

Comment: @RobG const is a perfect choice because it's block-scoped, unlike var, and it's redeclared after each interation. let would also work, but since j doesn't change it's value inside for block const is better choice

Comment: @pauk960—regarding "*it's redeclared after each interation*", they aren't. Declarations of all types are only processed once on entering an execution context, see [*ECMA-262 §13.2.14*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-blockdeclarationinstantiation).

Comment: @RobG Winky aside, 2 extra chars is a small price to pay for preventing inadvertent reassignments. `const` communicates intent clearly: "I declare that this variable will never be reassigned". That simplifies cognitive load for reading the code and adds expressiveness -- when you _do_ use `let` (on rare occasions), it communicates "this variable _will_ be reassigned". `const` by default generally makes for better-quality code, smaller functions, fewer pieces of mutable state to keep track of than `let`-heavy, reassignment-happy code.

Comment: @ggorlen—not really the right place for this discussion, however I'll reply once. The concept of constants has been around as long as mathematics and means an invariant value. In the absence of a specific keyword, they were identified using all upper case letters (e.g. Math.PI). Semantically, that is how constants remain. Using *const* for variables such as objects that are then assigned new properties and values is not semantically consistent, e.g. `const obj = {}; obj.prop = 'value';`. *let*, on the other hand, is semantically consistent.

Answer (score 490):

You could use the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (code adapted from [this site](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/)):

```
function shuffle(array) {
    let counter = array.length;

    // While there are elements in the array
    while (counter > 0) {
        // Pick a random index
        let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);

        // Decrease counter by 1
        counter--;

        // And swap the last element with it
        let temp = array[counter];
        array[counter] = array[index];
        array[index] = temp;
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on what Closure Compiler does to speed this up?

Comment: @BrianMortenson: Pass it through and look at the resulting code. It replaces the `while` loop with a `for` loop and turns `counter > 0` into `0 < counter`. I'm not entirely sure what parts speed it up, but the end result is a tiny bit faster than the original.

Comment: That first answer seems to have a bug. About once in every 15 runs I get an extra `undefined` column. http://jsfiddle.net/tomasswood/z8zm7/

Comment: @ThomasWood: Yep, you're right. alltom's suggestion wasn't correct.

Comment: The `~~` is even better than `| 0`: `index = ~~(Math.random() * counter)`

Comment: @rvighne: I tested both and `| 0` was marginally faster.

Comment: there is still a bug in this answer!

try:

shuffle([1,2,3]);

the value "1" is never on position 0 in the returned array

Comment: Why you just don't use random + Array.prototype.sort? It's easier and less code than both answers.

Comment: @Volter9: Because the distribution isn't going to be uniform.

Comment: really interesting post by jeff atwood about this algorithm. http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/  I wanted to know why it is implemented the way it is

Comment: Would be better if some of the `let`s were replaced with `const` as they aren't modified at all, except for `counter`.

Comment: be aware this changes the initial array, its not a functional approach. Just leaving this here for anyone that is blindely copying this (as I did lol).